# Program type already present: javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using this open source keyboad code. https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard .
I want to integrate google drive in app. Issues i am facing is that when i add this

```
 implementation ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.28.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude module: 'annotations'
    exclude group: 'javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue'

}

implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.28.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude module: 'annotations'
    exclude group: 'javax.annotation.CheckForSigned'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group: 'javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude module: 'annotations'
    exclude group: 'javax.annotation.CheckForSigned'
    exclude group: 'javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue'
}
```

Because of those library it keep me showing this error

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task 
 ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
 > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging 
 dex archives: 
 Learn how to resolve the issue at 
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
 Program type already present: javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
```

I have already tried with exclude module and group still is showing me error .
I am using google drive Rest api. This one https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk
 Please help me.

Comment: Maybe try `exclude group: 'javax.annotation'` in excludes block and check that duplicate implementation of same library is not found in submodules, also check that versions are same for related google libraries.

Comment: I did ,but still not solved.

Comment: Check dependencies with `gradlew app:dependencies`, maybe it can show duplicates and/or version mismatches.